# Caesar Cipher with a Keyword - Python

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am a student in school and am currently doing a Caesar Cipher on Python as a programming assignment. The first task was to create a program that asked the user for a message, offset and the code would either encrypt or decrypt based on the user's decision. I'm not experienced at all in Python and thus I am not the best at it so here is my code that is rather simple:

```
message = input("What would you like your message to be? ")

key = int(input("What would you like your offset to be? ")) 

count = 0
while count == 0:
    mode = str(input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? "))
    if mode == "encrypt" or mode == "Encrypt" or mode == "E" or mode == "e":
        count = count + 1
    elif mode == "decrypt" or mode == "Decrypt" or mode == "D" or mode == "d":
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print("You need to enter in a valid answer. Please try again. ")  

letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 

translated_message = ""

for character in message:
    if character in letters:
       number = letters.find(character)
       if mode == "encrypt" or mode == "Encrypt" or mode == "E" or mode == "e":
           number = number + key
       elif mode == "decrypt" or mode == "Decrypt" or mode == "D" or mode == "d":
           number = number - key



       if number >= len(letters):
            number = number - len(letters)
       elif number < 0:
            number = number + len(letters)


       translated_message = translated_message + letters[number]

    else:
         translated_message = translated_message + character

print(translated_message)
```

Now the next task is to create a Caesar Cipher with a keyword which repeats itself as many times as needed to fit the message that the user input. So if I had a user input "the password" as their message and "key" as their keyword then key would be repeated as many times to fit the text, and the program should add the numerical values together to create the new encrypted or decrypted message. For instance, the first letter of the translated message would be Y as 10(K) + 15(P) = 25(Y).

I have attempted to expand on my original code by adding this feature but I am unable to do so. If anyone were able to help me out in using this code and expanding on it to add this feature, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is neither a homework completion service nor a tutoring service.

Comment: Sorry I don't really know how this works. I thought you were allowed to do this kind of thing. Is there another place/website where I can post this type of question?

Comment: In what way are you *unable to do so*

Comment: Well I have tried a variety of things but none of them are even getting me close to a potential solution due to the fact that as I said, I'm not very experienced in Python.

Comment: We will help you with the difficulties if you post them, what you hoped they'd do, what they actually did. See how to ask a [mcve].

Comment: Why have you taken key as an integer

Comment: Also 25 should be `Z` as the indexing is starting from `0`

Comment: For help with your second problem, "Caesar with keyword," research the [Vigenère cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher).

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
message = input("What would you like your message to be? ")

key = input("What would you like your offset to be? ")

count = 0
while count == 0:
    mode = str(input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? "))
    if mode == "encrypt" or mode == "Encrypt" or mode == "E" or mode == "e":
        count = count + 1
    elif mode == "decrypt" or mode == "Decrypt" or mode == "D" or mode == "d":
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print("You need to enter in a valid answer. Please try again. ")  

letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 

translated_message = ""

index = 0
for character in message:
    if character in letters:
       number = letters.find(character)
       if mode == "encrypt" or mode == "Encrypt" or mode == "E" or mode == "e":
           number = number + (ord(key[index]) - ord('a'))
       elif mode == "decrypt" or mode == "Decrypt" or mode == "D" or mode == "d":
           number = number - (ord(key[index]) - ord('a'))
       index = index+1
       index = index % len(key)


       if number >= len(letters):
            number = number - len(letters)
       elif number < 0:
            number = number + len(letters)


       translated_message = translated_message + letters[number]

    else:
         translated_message = translated_message + character

print(translated_message)
```

Also note that : 10(K) + 15(P) = 25(Z), because indexing starts from 0.

Comment: Here key = "key", so index helps to get each character, i.e `key[index = 0] = 'k'`, `key[index = 1] = e`, and the line `index = index % len(key)` is used to set the index back to 0, when we reach the end of the key, so that the key can repeat itself.

Comment: `ord(character)` => it gives the ASCII value of a character i.e an fixed integer value corresponding to a character, you can read more about here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: when i do `ord(character) - ord('a')` it gives me the corresponding index in the letters string, eg :- the ASCII value of `'a'` is 97, and the ASCII value of `'k'` is 107 so : `ord('k') - ord('a') = 107 - 97 = 10`, i.e giving the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
def encrypt(text, key):
    cryptotext = ""
    keylen = len(key)
    for i, char in enumerate(text):
        if char == " ":
            cryptotext += " "
        else:
            cryptotext += chr(((ord(char)-97+ord(key[i%keylen])-96)%26)+97)
    return cryptotext

def decrypt(ciphretext, key):
    text = ""
    keylen = len(key)
    for i, cichar in enumerate(ciphretext):
        if cichar == " ":
            text += " "
        else:
            text += chr(((ord(cichar)-ord(key[i%keylen])-2)%26)+97)
    return text

print(encrypt("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "secret"))
print(decrypt("tgfvjzzmlbpffsrhvllyxnbrre", "secret"))
```

Comment: It would be constructive for the OP and future readers if you add a few words to explain how or why your answer works.